# Are the questions about getting/finding books on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is no [on-topic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) defined yet. So, I want to know whether the questions about finding/getting books are on-topic or not?

I found some questions like [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/english-translation-of-karnata-bharata-kathamanjari-kumara-vyasa-mahabharatha), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8228/where-to-find-manusmriti-with-sanskrit-hindi-translation) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/where-can-i-find-the-authentic-and-complete-vedas-online-hindi-english). I also want to ask some questions. Further Can one ask for finding/getting book(s) in particular language?

Comment: This was already discussed here: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/132/36 Yeah, finding books is on topic.  We even have a [tag:translation-request] tag for this purpose.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan But the upvote on that meta is changed now